# extracting data from file python

Tags: python, file

I have a dataset containing data blocks as shown below:

$TIME

data lines goes here....

$TIME

data lines goes here....

$TIME

data lines goes here....

This data block is repeated roughly around 101 time in my file

How can I extract data lines between two data blocks is what i am trying to figure out using python???

I want to make use of python built-in string methods and not use any external libraries or so.

Any help would be grateful

Comment: You need to read alternate lines from the file ?

Comment: No actually I have about 30000 rows of data after the header line that i need to read and append it to an array and then proceed extracting the next 30000 rows of data till the end of file is reached. There are 101 such data blocks in my file

Comment: Is it always `$TIME`?

Comment: What do you want exactly : just filter out `$TIME` lines, put each block in a file, keep only first data block (or nth data block) ? As currently written it is rather *unclear*.

Comment: i need to extract all the 101 blocks data and append it to an array thats it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
def main():
    isTime = False
    newLists = []
    with open("time.txt", 'r') as newFile:
        result = newFile.readlines()
        for line in result:
            if "$TIME" in line:
                isTime = True
            elif isTime:
                newLists.append(line)

    for line in newLists:
        print line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Did you test calling `newFile.readline()` after `newFile.readlines()` ?

Comment: Oh sorry. Forgot to delete that line. Edited.

Comment: Test what you are doing. If I correctly read, you keep only one line after each `$TIME`. And I'm not sure it is really useful to first load all file in memory as you process it line by line. But I cannot tell you more, I really did not understood what OP wanted exactly :-(

Comment: how can i get the next element to be processed the same way.I mean to say there are multiple data lines after the #TIME header region not just a single data line @vahnevileyes

Comment: @AKKI According to your description after $TIME there are datalines. This process will read the file. Stored it in a list. That list will be iterated, detect ($TIME) and skipped that line and only store the datalines into a new list.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Before I post my answer I am testing it. However, that line doesn't seem to produce any error. Anyway, Thanks for pointing the correction.

Comment: @vahnevileyes : AKKI said there are multiple datalines after each `$TIME`. You current code only keeps first one.

Comment: @AKKI : I have updated my answer. Can you try on your end?Currently working for me. Thanks

Comment: but i see it doing only the very first line after that the script stops executing

Comment: could you please post your updated code which does it for multiple line please.urgent @vahnevileyes

Comment: @AKKI : I have already updated the code and should do the process. It will procur multiple datalines.